# django; Is there way to combine the result of filtering objects

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I'm filtering an Object but maybe I'm using dumb way. What I want to do is to get object named Message if the sender and receiver match. 
I'm creating a chat-like page. Currently 'views.py' is like this,

```
def  message(request, user_id):
'''Direct message between users'''

    #Get an user that the user is sending messages to
    someone = CustomUser.objects.get(id=user_id)

    #Get past messages

    past_messages = Message.objects.filter(someone=someone, user=request.user)
```

`models.py` is like this

```
class Message(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    #Has a relationship with the user
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='myself')

    #Has a relationship with the someone who the user is talking to
    someone = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='someone')
```

But for this way, I can get only messages I sent and cannot get messages the user I'm chatting sent to me.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to combine the result of filtering objects, basically I want to get both messages the user send to someone and the ones someone send to the user and order them by date.  But I didn't come up with a good way to do it.
Anyone who can give me tips?

Basically what I want to do is get both `filter(someone=someone, user=request.user)` and `filter(someone=request.user, user=someone)`

Comment: Can you share the `CustomUser` model (or at least explain if `id` is here a custom field)?

Comment: Can you explain why `user` points to `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`, but `someone` points to a `CustomUser`, what is the difference between the two?

Comment: I'm using google login auth and `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` is for associating the user who is logging in with the model and in `settinngs.py` it's like this `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'`

Comment: so both are `CustomUser`s? Then perhaps it is better to use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well we can make a filter that filters on a *disjunction* of two cases:

1. `user` is `request.user` and `someone` is `user_id`; and
2. `someone` is `request.user` and `user` is `user_id`.

We can write this as:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def  message(request, user_id):
    past_messages = Message.objects.filter(
        Q(user=request.user, someone_id=user_id) |
        Q(user_id=user_id, someone=request.user)
    )
```

We thus query for `Message`s in two directions with *one* query.